# What event is fired when all SkinSparts are available in a SkinnableComponent?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm (slowly) learning Flex 4 and working on skinning a custom component that extends SkinnableComponent. The component is all in ActionScript and essentially looks like this:

```
package components
{
    import spark.components.supportClasses.SkinnableComponent

    [SkinState("normal")]
    [SkinState("over")] 
    [SkinState("selected")]     
    public class AccountSummary extends SkinnableComponent
    {
        [Bindable]
        public var itemIndex:int = 0;

        [Bindable]
        public var accountName:String = "";

        [Bindable]
        public var accountNumber:String = "";   

        [Bindable]
        public var currentBalance:String = "";  

        [SkinPart(required="true")]
        public var lblAccountName:Label;

        [SkinPart(required="true")]
        public var lblCurrentBalance:Label;

        [SkinPart(required="true")]
        public var lblAccountNumber:Label;

        [SkinPart(required="true")]
        public var lblLastUpdated:Label;

        public function AccountSummary()
        {
            super();

            lblAccountName.text = accountName;
            lblCurrentBalance.text = currentBalance;
            lblAccountNumber.text = "Acc: " + accountNumber;
            lblLastUpdated.text = "Last Updated: "; 
        }

        override protected function getCurrentSkinState():String
        {
            return "normal";
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is on NULL REFERENCES in the Constructor for the various SkinParts, because they're not created yet. I'm trying to find out when is the best time to access them to assign their .text values. I know I can override partAdded() and add the .text value as each part is added, but I'd rather just listen for some magic event that is dispatched when they're all available.

I'm not sure whether or not it matters, but the accountName, accountNumber variables are assigned by using a repeater with a dataProvider on the host component. I'm not sure if that too has something to do with when the data is available to the AccountSummary component - which may also needed to be waited on. I was able to successfully use FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE to assign all my .text values to the SkinParts, but is that the right event/best practice? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read up on the [Flex 4 Component LifeCycle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html), specifically the piece about [component instantiation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html#WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7ffc).  Nothing will be created at the time the constructor executes.  The values you are referencing (accountName, lblCurrentBalance. etc...) will not have moved beyond the default states either.

You want to set your default values in the partAdded() method.  Rewrite your constructor code to something like this:

```
    public function AccountSummary()
    {
        super();

    }

override protected function partAdded(partName : String, instance: Object):void{
 super.partAdded(partName, instance);
 if(instance == lblAccountName){
            lblAccountName.text = accountName;
 else if(instance == lblCurrentBalance){

 } else if (instance == lblCurrentBalance){
   lblCurrentBalance.text = currentBalance;
 } else if (instance == lblAccountNumber){
  lblAccountNumber.text = "Acc: " + accountNumber;
 } else if (instance == lblLastUpdated){
  lblLastUpdated.text = "Last Updated: "; 
 }

}
```

If you're a new programmer, you may want to devote some time to learning some basic programming concepts.  This [ActionScript 3 Guide](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/index.html) may help you get started.  If you have experience in other languages, but are new to Flex, I strongly suggest spending a couple of days reading through the [full flex documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/index.html) to help get your head around it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but as my question stated - I was hoping to not have to resort to partAdded and do checks for each part one by one. I was just looking for some event that fired after ALL parts were added.

Comment: I'll check out the component life cycles though as you mentioned. That's probably a good idea.

Comment: Alright, reading on the life cycle shows me there are several events after the constructor, partAdded and before creationComplete that I could tap into which would find all the skin parts available at once.

Comment: @WesleyJohnson Sorry, I missed your comment related to to partAdded in the original question. I strongly suggest you do not set these in relation to an event.  The best alternative to partAdded() is to use commitProperties().  Both partAdded() and/or commitProperties() will give you more long-term flexibility than listening to an instantiation specific event.  I use partAdded() for initial creation property setting (lblLastUpdated.text is a good example) and commitProperties() for handling dynamic changes (such as lblCurrentBalance.text )

Comment: Great, thanks for the additional advice. I'll give it a go. :)